# How to call one more fucntion in rowinfo react table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I want to call one more function like editUserDetail in table row onclick.pls suggest any solution.

````
   ``` <Table columns={columns} data = {userData} rowInfo={this.deleteUserDetail} styles={controlPanelTableStyle}/>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can call one function onClick and then call multiple functions inside that function.

```
<Table columns={columns} data = {userData} 
         rowInfo={this.deleteUserDetail} 
         styles={controlPanelTableStyle}
onClick={()=>{
 firstFunction();
secondFunction();
}}/>
```